# Answer has been posted update bug (Not really a big deal)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, notifications, alerts

I noticed a small bug when on stack overflow.  These are the steps to reproduce.

1. Go into a question.
2. post a comment.
3. while posting a comment, have an update about an answer being posted come up.
4. Click the notification to update it.
5. Finish posting comment
6. Navigate away from question.

You get an alert asking if you want to abandon your edits on the page.
Like I said, small bug... just thought you would like to know.  If not, then feel free to tell me to shut my stupid mouth and close this question.

Comment: It's not a bug .. it's a feature